# native php session in codeigniter 3 " A session had already been started - ignoring"

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, config, kcfinder

I use native php session to secure site/assets/kcfinder/browse.php on kcfinder...
because kcfinder can't read sessions from the codeigniter that I made....
can anyone help me, please ...

=> My Form

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= base_url('Authentication/login'); ?>">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="staticEmail" placeholder="email@example.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="******">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

=> Authentication.php (Controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Authentication extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // load libary native session

        $this->load->library('Nativesession', 'nativesession');
    }

    function index()
    {
        // $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'email',
            'Email',
            'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean',
            ['required' => 'Email Harus Di isi', 'valid_email' => 'Harus email yang valid']
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'password',
            'Password',
            'trim|required|xss_clean',
            ['required' => 'Password Harus Di isi']
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $data['judul'] = 'Selamat Datang';
            $this->session->set_flashdata(
                'pesan',
                '<div class="alert alert-warning fixed alert-dismissible fade show fixed" role="alert">
                authentication Failed !
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>'
            );
            $this->load->view('Home/Template/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('Home/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('Home/Template/footer');
        } else {
            //Jiko Lolos Validasi buat private function
            $this->_login();
        }
    }

    private function _login()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
        $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
        //perintah select dari tabel user  where email = email inputan
        $user       = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $email])->row_array();
        // var_dump($user);
        // die;
        if ($email == $user['email']) {
            // set native session jika username benar
            if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
                $this->nativesession->set('status', 'loggedin');
                var_dump($this->nativesession->set('status', 'loggedin'));
                die;
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata(
                    'pesan',
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger fixed alert-dismissible fade show fixed" role="alert">
                    Wrong Password !
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>'
                );
                redirect(base_url());
            }
            // redirect ke halaman blog
            // redirect('blog');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata(
                'pesan',
                '<div class="alert alert-info fixed alert-dismissible fade show fixed" role="alert">
                Account Not Found !
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>'
            );
            // redirect ke login jika username salah
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->nativesession->delete('status');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

=> Nativesession.php (Libraries)

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nativesession
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }
    // function untuk meng-set session
    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
    // function untuk memanggil session
    public function get($key)
    {
        return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : null;
    }
    // function untuk menghapus session
    public function delete($key)
    {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

I called the session at /assets/kcfinder/config.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['status']) == 'loggedin'){
    $status = false;
}else{
    $status = true;
}
```

Comment: Have u tried using codeigniter's inbuilt session library?

Comment: What's your question about all these code? What have you tried to debug your problem?